# Is it possible to create an EF relationship using char fields?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, char

I have 2 entities that look like this:

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status")]
    public char StatusCode { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class UserStatus {
    [Key]
    public char StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create an Entity Framework Core relationship using the StatusCode property. There are tables in my SQL Server DB mirroring these entities. Unfortunately, I didn't build them and can't change the datatypes.

The UserStatus table looks like this:

```
| StatusCode (char) | StatusDescription (varchar(100)) |
| ----------------- | -------------------------------- |
| A                 | Active                           |
| L                 | LockedOut                        |
| N                 | NotActivated                     |
```

Whilst this code seems to run, the JSON I get back when calling via a WebAPI controller is this:

```
{
    "UserId": "abcdefg",
    "FirstName": "Jon",
    "LastName": "Snow",
    "Email": "jonsnow@winterfell.co.uk",
    "LastLogon": "9999-12-31T00:00:00",
    "StatusCode": "A",
    "Status": null
}
```

What I'm expecting to see is something other than null for Status, e.g.:

```
{
    "UserId": "abcdefg",
    "FirstName": "Jon",
    "LastName": "Snow",
    "Email": "jonsnow@winterfell.co.uk",
    "LastLogon": "9999-12-31T00:00:00",
    "StatusCode": "A",
    "Status": 
    {
        StatusCode: "A",
        StatusDescription: "Active"
    }
}
```

Can anyone see the error I'm making?

Comment: You're not showing your query but you're probably missing the .Include() for the StatusCode property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no problem with the relation that you made between entities in order to get a data that you want you should do the same thing as below for your ef query :

```
 var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ToList();
```

I mean you should load the data in your query using **.Include()** method.
I hope it become handy for you.

Comment: That was exactly my issue. I think the null entry was throwing me into thinking there'd been an error with the relationship. I expected to see something like "Object" suggesting the relationship was good but the data just hadn't been brought. Glad it was so simple, thank you.